# message only for first request in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net

How can I show message on website only for first request? 
For example I have code:

```
protected void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Session["msg"] = "Thx for email.";
  Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?msg='true'");
}
```

Should I set session on null in Site.Master after show message like that??

```
<% 
if(Session["msg"]!=null) 
{
  Response.Write(Session["msg"].ToString()); 
  Session["msg"] = null;
}
%>
```

Comment: what do you mean by first time, you dont want to show it when the page is refreshed or reloaded..if you want this then you can write your code within `(autoPostBack = false)` condition

Comment: `if (!IsPostBack) Response.Write(Session["msg"].ToString());` do like this in the page load event...

Answer (score 1):

Yes also you should check for if page is posted back or not. So you should write

```
 <% 
    if (!IsPostBack)
       {
    if(Session["msg"]!=null) 
    {
      Response.Write(Session["msg"].ToString()); 
      Session["msg"] = null;
    }
    }
    %>
```